is this a typo? doob inequality bound.
shouldnt this be $\epsilon$, not $\epsilon^2$? you use doob inequality, then $E[M_\infty^2]=E[\langle M,M \rangle_\infty]\leq \epsilon$ for M a  continuous martingale bounded in $L^2$.


Is this from a book?

@Snoop Le Gall "Brownian motion, martingales, and stochastic processes"

I would be inclined to agree since for any fixed $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we would have $E[\sup_{t\leq N}|M^{n,\varepsilon}t|^2]\leq 4 E[|M^{n,\varepsilon}N|^2]=4 E[\langle M^{n}\rangle{N\wedge T^n\varepsilon} ]\leq 4\varepsilon$ and then conclude by monotone convergence sending $N\to \infty$.

@Snoop right. ok thank you for confirming
